# Where to store sensitive uploaded file?

Tags: uploads, security, filesystem

I'm developing a plugin. Where is the best place to store a user uploaded file that is sensitive in nature? It should not be web accessible. 
Given the encoding of the file, it's necessary that it be uploaded, as opposed to storing it in the database.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the file?

Comment: It's a tls certificate. It will be passed as part of the header when making curl requests. (--cacert [file])

Answer (score 0):

Upload files at anywhere ( normally create your own folder inside `wp-content/uploads` folder ), you can create `.htaccess` file and `index.html` files inside the folder to restrict the files from direct access.

Keep `index.html` blank and add `deny from all` text in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Doesn't using .htaccess assume that my plugin is running from an Apache webserver?

Comment: Don't know more about serve, but please check this may help you: https://www.keycdn.com/support/htaccess-not-working